# What is the importance of Rcon in Rjindael's key expansion from a security prespective?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, algorithm-design, finite-field

I do not see why the `Rcon` function is important, it looks like a waste of cycles.

$$\operatorname{Rcon}(i) = 2^{i-1} \bmod p(x)$$ is in  $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$, where $p(x)$ is the irreducible polynomial $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$.

Comment: the round constants are generally hardcoded and take up only a handful of bytes, as the key/block size combinations are less for AES than for Rijndael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Section 3.8 of "**The Design of Rijndael**", authored by the cipher's creators, the purpose is to eliminate symmetries in the key schedule:

> The non-linear function is realized by means of the application of $\mathrm S_\mathrm{RD}$ to the four bytes of the column, an additional cyclic rotation of the bytes within the column and **the addition of a round constant (for elimination of symmetry).** The round constants are independent of $\mathrm N_\mathrm k$, and defined by a recursion rule in $\operatorname{GF}(2^8)$:

(Emphasis mine.)

Section 5.8 elaborates a bit more on this:

> For the key schedule in Rijndael the criteria are less ambitious. Basically, the key schedule is there for three purposes.
>
> 1. **The first one is the introduction of asymmetry. Asymmetry in the key schedule prevents symmetry in the round transformation and between the rounds leading to weaknesses or allows attacks.** Examples of such weaknesses are the complementation property of the DES or weak keys such as in the DES [28]. Examples of attacks that exploit symmetry are slide attacks.

(Emphasis mine.)

To summarize: Adding the round constants $\mathrm{Rcon}$ is a very cheap way (it's not *that* many cycles) to **make each step of the key schedule *slightly* different**, avoiding a variety of attacks that have become apparent in the past.

Comment: if Rcon(i) replaced with i, won't make any difference since Rcon[0-32] are unique.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a bit more detail to [the first answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42787/12164), a round constant in a key schedule (or the main cipher) protects against attacks based on the symmetry of rounds.

The AES schedule uses the user input key to produce a set of unguessable and unrelated round keys.  The round key generation function is the same for each round however.  The round constant changes each round a little to avoid symmetry. Without the round constant, weak or related key attacks become possible.

Even with the round constant, an impractical related key attack is [possible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/related-key-attacks-on-aes).

The general area of interest here is symmetric attacks on a cipher. The [Slide Attack](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/) and similar are good examples.  There are several papers of interest on that link.

As a very simple related key example, if the key schedule is just based on a long user input key then a key like #FFFFFFFF...FFFF will lead to every round being exactly the same. A related key attack is easily created by producing a pair of keys with an difference (likely xor) of #FFFF00000..0000.  So if the round key size is 32-bits then all of the rounds will use the same key except the first round. Differential cryptanalysis on a single round is likely simple thus the cipher is quickly broken.

[Weak keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_key) are too be avoided as a matter of design.  The round constant can help with that as well but are [insufficient](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26978/blowfish-weak-keys).