# S-AES RC[i] Generation. Can someone explain how to generate the RC[i]s for these two problems I have?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, key-schedule

I don't know exactly how to find the RC[ 1 ] of 80, or the RC[2] of 30. 
Can someone explain how to find them?

Here is a picture of the problem I am having with two questions.

[image: S-AES HELP WITH RC constants]

Comment: Source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question missing some information about the source, however, one can give an answer based on S-AES i.e. Simplified AES.

There is a nice definition of S-AES [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads222/ebook/1044300/%E9%99%84%E5%BD%95P%20Simplified%20AES%20(S-AES).pdf).

The Round Constant (RC) or the other name R-con has [10 values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule) for AES and utilized for the key schedule to [eliminate the symmetry](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42787/18298) by making each step of the key schedule slightly different.

```
i      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
RC[i] 01  02  04  08  10  20  40  80  1B  36
```

S-AES has defined only 2-rounds, thus the designers of S-AES have to choose only; two RC values. This is just a selection issue, not a generation as in [AES-key schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule).

- RCon[1] = 80
- RCon[2] = 30

---

Note: S-AES is only an oversimplified AES for educational use.